# How to SSH into local ubuntu from Windows desktop without internet?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ethernet

Is it possible to SSH from my Windows PC into my ubuntu machine (local) without internet? I have my main PC (Windows) connected to the internet via ethernet. My Ubuntu machine is NOT connected to the internet, there is no ethernet cable or wifi connection at all. However, is it even possible to SSH into the Ubuntu machine despite it not having any internet connection, from my local machines? if so, how do you do it?

Comment: If it's reachable from your PC then you can SSH to it.

Comment: Is it connected to your local network? The machine needs to be connected so some network in order to be reachable.

Comment: What exactly is your "ubuntu machine"? A dedicated PC running Ubuntu? A virtual machine running on the same PC using VirtualBox or something like that? An dual-boot alternative OS on your PC?

Answer (score 1):

You need a communications channel between the two computers. It can be a network cable, or a wireless connection, but also a connection via modem, a serial cable (for example SLIP), a parallel cable (for example PLIP), sound, bluetooth, light modulation, software defined radio...

Internet has nothing to do with it, for `ssh` you just need TCP, that in turn needs IP connectivity (that is, the computers have the IP addresses that can be reached from each other) that will work on the communications channel between the two computers, whatever it might be.